# Routing not working on IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, routes, webforms, iis-7.5

I know that are innumerous posts out there with this problem and solutions, but I think I have tried all of them and I can't get rid of the 404 error.

I contacted my host provider to get some info.

They told me and I quote:

> This site is hosted in IIS 7.
>
> The application pool used by the application ‘xxxx’ is already set to ‘DefaultAppPoolPT_DOTNET40’ which is in .Net framework 4.0, Classic pipeline mode.
>
> For wildcard application mapping in IIS 7, it’s done in the web.config file.

Although they said that is IIS7, when I go to the website I get this headers:

Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5

But I don't know if is relevant or not for this case.

As so many others I followed this guide http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668202.aspx without success. I tried the famous

```
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

without luck.

.html files and images works fine. .aspx files doesn't.
I'm just wondering if is a web.config problem or if is IIS that is not configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talked once again with the hosting provider they told me that

> the application pool user of the application ‘xxxx’ doesn’t have
>   access to the folder.

After they solved this problem the website was up and running fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Intergrated managed pipeline.

And under system.webServer node ,you should add the following config.

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
```